# UWP xUnit is really challenging me

Tags: uwp, xunit

## Running from the command line

I'm running the latest everything VS2019, Windows 10 v10.0.18363.

I certainly can't get test explorer to work so I thought I'd try the command line.

```
vstest.console.exe c:\temp\WordToMarkdownUnitTests\bin\x64\Debug\UnitTestProject.build.appxrecipe /platform:x64
```

Here is the error:

```
DEP7100: Failed to activate app '4979c77f-dafb-41b1-9b6b-c55405d624ad_d9fbpvqm16pa0!vstest.executionengine.universal.App' with parameters '--port 59383 --endpoint 127.0.0.1:059383 --role client --parentprocessid 25268 --telemetryoptedin false'. The text associated with this error code could not be found.

The text associated with this error code could not be found.

App activation failed.
Failed to initialize client proxy: could not connect to test process.
Closing app with package full name '4979c77f-dafb-41b1-9b6b-c55405d624ad_1.0.0.0_x64__d9fbpvqm16pa0'.

Test Run Aborted.
```

I've been chasing my tail on this for a while. Any clues?

[image: The myriad of nuget packages]

I finally just wrote my own test harness right into my app. Works great and my tests are always discovered since they are compiled into my executable.

[image: Home grown test harness]

Answer (score 0):

My solution of building my own test harness/runner could have saved  me a huge amount of time. It works great and is 100% reliable. Plus it gives me full control on how I execute the tests without the overhead of another visual studio project.